# Eclipse. Error(s) found in manifest configuration. how to fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I just taken the project - I checkout this and I want to resolve all problems

one of the problems which I cannot to resolve

```
Error(s) found in manifest configuration (org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:bundle:default-bundle:package)
```

it refers to this row of pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
```

code around this row:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.squeakysand.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsptld-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <shortName>ctc</shortName>
                    <processTagFiles>true</processTagFiles>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>//this row
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Include-Resource>
                            META-INF/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.tld=${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.tld,
                            {maven-resources}
                        </Include-Resource>
                        <Sling-Bundle-Resources>
                            /META-INF/tags
                        </Sling-Bundle-Resources>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Please, help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old question but for future Google results.

The issue is an old version of maven-bundle-plugin, specifically 2.3.7.  Updating the pom.xml to use the latest (currently 2.5.0) fixed the issue.

Comment: I have this problem and updated to 2.5.4, but the same error persists.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the maven console (see the chapter "Enabling the Maven Console" here: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363817/Introduction-to-m2eclipse).
2. Project right click->Maven->Update Project
3. You will see the real manifest problem in error messages in m2e console. Then you can fix them.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs if the files referenced in the Include-Resource tag are not found by Eclipse. E.g. if the files are generated during the build process and Eclipse cannot execute one of the build steps (because of a missing m2e connector for instance). In this case check the build process and install required m2e connectors if available.